# An equation flavored Fermat

Tags: elementary-number-theory

An undergraduate student surprised me with a problem that caught my attention, which I found very difficult because of its similarity to Fermat's last theorem. But it was not so difficult ......

Prove that the equation 
$$\sqrt[7]x+\sqrt[7]y=\sqrt[7]z$$ has an infinite number of integer solutions.

Comment: If $a+b=c$, then your equality is true for $x=a^7$, $y=b^7$ and $z=c^7$.

Comment: @Emanuele Bottazzi: Exactly, and you can take arbitrary $n$ instead of $7$.

Answer (score 1):

$$x = 1^7 \quad y = m^7 \quad z = (m+1)^7$$

$\forall m > 0$?

Nothing special about either $1$ or $7$, indeed any $x = n^7$ with $z = (m+n)^7$ will do. Modified examples also show something similar for any positive integer $k$-th roots, not just $7$.